# xml schema validation for large schema files

Tags: xsd

I'm trying to use xmllint to validate the schema, which I believe uses the libxml2 library underneath.

The problem is I have a unusually large schema file in about 10MB. When I do this:

```
xmllint --schema j9.xsd --noout jsample.xml
```

I got the following errors:

```
j9.xsd:65535: element annotation: Schemas parser error : Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}complexType': The content is not valid. Expected is (annotation?, (simpleContent | complexContent | ((group | all | choice | sequence)?, ((attribute | attributeGroup)*, anyAttribute?)))).
j9.xsd:65535: element annotation: Schemas parser error : Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}complexType': The content is not valid. Expected is (annotation?, (simpleContent | complexContent | ((group | all | choice | sequence)?, ((attribute | attributeGroup)*, anyAttribute?)))).
```

.....
This goes on and on. Apparently the line number of error should NOT be 65535, if there is an error. I'm wondering if there is another library that do not have this limitation, or if someone knows how to fix this bug. Thanks!

Comment: did the patch mentioned by Chaim worked for you?

Comment: Patch work fine. I'm don't know for which version they was writen, so i'm patch libxml version 2.7.6 manually, and now get right line number for error lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WONTFIX bug for libxml2. https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=325533 . Unofficial patch is attached to the bugreport, haven't tried it yet ...